# Activate WordPress plugins in Database

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins

I tried to find a conflict in my WordPress installation and for that I have deactivated all plugins. But now I'm only having a white screen. So I need to re-activate all the plugins through the database. I have tried [this solution](https://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/). But this only works if the plugins were active before - that is not the case for me. So any solutions are very welcome! Thanks!

Comment: As this isn't really a programming question, you might have more luck on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ (But, the best first step is probably to look in your server's error logs, which may well tell you the actual *reason* for the white screen.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I found the answer by myself: I copied the text from the table '_transient_plugin_slugs' in wp_options - works well!